# go udp requests (packet) loss

Tags: go, udp

i wrote simple server and client for tcp and udp connection

```
package main

//server.go

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    tcp := 0
    udp := 0

    defer func(o, t *int) {
        fmt.Println(*o, *t)
    }(&tcp, &udp)

    go func() {
        l, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", &net.TCPAddr{
            IP:   net.ParseIP("0.0.0.0"),
            Port: 3000,
        })
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        b := make([]byte, 24)

        for {
            conn, err := l.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                continue
            }

            n, err := conn.Read(b)
            if err != nil {
                continue
            }

            r := string(b[:n])

            if r == "close" {
                conn.Close()
                break
            } else {
                _, err = conn.Write([]byte("pong"))
                if err != nil {
                    continue
                }
            }

            conn.Close()
            tcp++
        }

        l.Close()
    }()

    go func() {
        conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", &net.UDPAddr{
            IP:   net.ParseIP("0.0.0.0"),
            Port: 3000,
        })
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        b := make([]byte, 24)

        for {
            n, addr, err := conn.ReadFromUDP(b)
            if err != nil {
                continue
            }

            r := string(b[:n])

            if r == "close" {
                break
            } else {
                _, err = conn.WriteToUDP([]byte("pong"), addr)
                if err != nil {
                    continue
                }
            }

            udp++
        }

        conn.Close()
    }()

    signals := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(signals, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    <-signals
}
```

```
package main

//client.go

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "strconv"
    "sync/atomic"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := "tcp"
    m := "ping"

    c := 1

    if len(os.Args) > 1 {
        t = os.Args[1]
    }

    if len(os.Args) > 2 {
        m = os.Args[2]
    }

    if len(os.Args) > 3 {
        c, _ = strconv.Atoi(os.Args[3])
    }

    tcp := int64(0)
    udp := int64(0)

    defer func(o, t *int64) {
        fmt.Println(*o, *t)
    }(&tcp, &udp)

    if c == 1 {
        if t == "tcp" {
            addr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", ":3000")
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, addr)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            _, err = conn.Write([]byte(m))
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            tcp++
        }

        if t == "udp" {
            addr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":3000")
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, addr)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            _, err = conn.Write([]byte(m))
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            udp++
        }

        os.Exit(0)
    }

    for i := 0; i < c; i++ {
        go func() {
            a1, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", ":3000")
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            c1, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, a1)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            _, err = c1.Write([]byte(m))
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            buf := make([]byte, 24)

            n, err := c1.Read(buf)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            if string(buf[:n]) != "pong" {
                panic(1)
            }

            err = c1.Close()
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            g := atomic.AddInt64(&tcp, 1)

            if g % 100 == 0 {
                fmt.Println("tcp", g)

                time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1000)
            }
        }()

        go func() {
            a2, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":3000")
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            c2, err := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, a2)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            _, err = c2.Write([]byte(m))
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            buf := make([]byte, 24)

            n, err := c2.Read(buf)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            if string(buf[:n]) != "pong" {
                panic(1)
            }

            err = c2.Close()
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            g := atomic.AddInt64(&udp, 1)

            if g % 100 == 0 {
                fmt.Println("udp", g)

                time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1000)
            }
        }()
    }


    signals := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(signals, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    <-signals
}
```

and get a strange behavior: not all udp requests are sent or handled on many connections.

When i sent 100 or 200 both server and client tells me that all requests worked but from 1000 there is a strange ~5% requests loss on udp for both server and client but no panic.
I know udp allows packet loss but 5% on localhost requests seems like an error.

Comment: *"but 5% on localhost requests seems like a error"* - why do you think this way? UDP is fire and forget - if you send to faster than what can be delivered or what can be handled by the other side then it is simply lost. TCP instead will slow down in this case so that nothing gets lost.

Comment: @steffen-ullrich i think it's wrong because one of previous versions was with sync.WaitGroup on client that performed wg.Done() on each requests and waited at the end with wg.Wait(). This version also has no panic but never exit.

Comment: You're trying to send 1000 UDP packets concurrently from 1000 connections. I'm surprised only 5% was lost. What is the point of this exercise? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Now it's not a real problem but i think a real server with 1000 connections should work correctly. People somehow make servers with 100k rps and it works correctly at most.

Comment: It's not necessarily the number of connections, but the rate of packets. You are sending them faster than you can read them, and because it's UDP there will be some packet loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know, the UDP is connectionless, so packet loss **may** be caused by this nature of UDP. There could be several ways to lower the rate of packet loss.

- Slow down the rate of packets sent on the client side
- Call [`SetWriteBuffer`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#IPConn.SetWriteBuffer) to increase the buffer size on the client side and set [`SetReadBuffer`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#IPConn.SetReadBuffer) to increase the buffer size on the server side

```golang
    conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, addr)

    err = conn.SetWriteBuffer(64 * 1024 * 1024)
```

- Check the system network information through `netstat -s -udp` and get UDP statistics information. You could try to change the default value of `rmem_max` and `rmem_default` on the server side. For more details, please refer to [1](https://linux-tips.com/t/udp-packet-drops-and-packet-receive-error-difference/237/2) and [2](https://www.sobyte.net/post/2022-05/linux-udp-packet-drop-debug/)